# Trouble with In-Game Currency Conversion

Tags: c#

I am writing a small mockup of an in-game currency system which is more or less like the Dungeons and Dragons currency system, or the EverquestII currency system. Basically I have four different types of currency: Copper, Silver, Gold, and Platinum. The system is done with an exchange rate of 100, so:

```
1 Platinum = 100 Gold.
1 Gold = 100 Silver.
1 Silver = 100 Copper.
```

The thing is, though, I can't quite figure out how to convert the money between each other, and by that I mean, I can't wrap my head around how to convert 12 Platinum to Copper coins, which given the hefty conversion rate will result in a pretty astronomical number.

Here is the class that I am using to hold the money:

```
public class CurrencyData
    {
        public enum CurrencyType
        {
            Copper ,
            Silver ,
            Gold ,
            Platinum
        }
        public uint Copper { get; set; }
        public uint Silver { get; set; }
        public uint Gold { get; set; }
        public uint Platinum { get; set; }

        public CurrencyData( uint platinum , uint gold , uint silver , uint copper )
        {
            Copper = copper;
            Silver = silver;
            Gold = gold;
            Platinum = platinum;
        }
    }
```

One of the issues that I am facing is reverse-exchange. By that I mean suppose I wanted to "Try" to convert 123 Copper to Silver. Well, that would result in 1 Silver coin, but then we have some remainder which cannot be converted because it requires 100 copper to make 1 silver coin. I would have an extra 23 copper coins remaining after the conversion which would need to get added back to the copper coin pile. How do I do that? And in general, what is the best way to convert the money in both directions?

EDIT:

Using the excellent examples below, this is the class that I inevitably ended up with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace NovaEngine4Framework.Framework.Game.Currency
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// CoinBag.cs
    /// v1.1.0
    /// Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic".
    /// LordKrythic@gmail.com
    /// 
    /// This class was created with the goal of replicating a "Dungeons and
    /// Dragons" or original "Everquest" style currency system. In which there
    /// are 4 different levels of currency: Copper, Silver, Gold, and Platinum.
    /// Each coin has a different monetary worth, such that Platinum is the most
    /// expensive coin, and Copper is the least expensive. The bag holds a desired
    /// amount of money, and can be dynamically exchanged with the other denominations
    /// at user whim. Each denomination is worth 100 of the lesser, so 1 Platinum is
    /// equal to 100 Gold and so on.
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class CoinBag
    {
        public enum Coins
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Copper is the lowest denominator of currency.
            /// It requires 100 Copper to make 1 Silver.
            /// </summary>
            Copper = 1 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// Silver is the second most common form of currency.
            /// It requires 100 Silver to Make 1 Gold.
            /// </summary>
            Silver = 2 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// Gold is the most common form of currency. It takes
            /// part in most expensive transactions.
            /// It requires 100 Gold to make 1 Platinum.
            /// </summary>
            Gold = 3 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// Platinum is a coin which most people never see. A single
            /// Platinum coin can purchase almost anything.
            /// 1 Platinum Coin = 100 Gold.
            /// 1 Platinum Coin = 10,000 Silver.
            /// 1 Platinum Coin = 1,000,000 Copper.
            /// </summary>
            Platinum = 4
        }
        private readonly Dictionary<Coins , long> _internalWallet;
        public const int CurrencyMinimum = 0;
        public const int CurrencyMaximum = 99999;
        public const String CopperName = "Copper";
        public const String SilverName = "Silver";
        public const String GoldName = "Gold";
        public const String PlatinumName = "Platinum";
        public const char CopperAbbreviation = 'c';
        public const char SilverAbbreviation = 's';
        public const char GoldAbbreviation = 'g';
        public const char PlatinumAbbreviation = 'p';
        public static readonly Color CopperTextColor = Color.SaddleBrown;
        public static readonly Color SilverTextColor = Color.Silver;
        public static readonly Color GoldTextColor = Color.Gold;
        public static readonly Color PlatinumTextColor = Color.SlateBlue;
        public long Copper { get { return _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ]; } }
        public long Silver { get { return _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ]; } }
        public long Gold { get { return _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ]; } }
        public long Platinum { get { return _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ]; } }

        public CoinBag( uint platinum , uint gold , uint silver , uint copper )
        {
            _internalWallet = new Dictionary<Coins , long>
            {
                {Coins.Platinum, platinum},
                {Coins.Gold, gold},
                {Coins.Silver, silver},
                {Coins.Copper, copper}
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases the chosen currency field by a desired amount.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">The amount to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type of currency that will be increased.</param>
        public void Add( uint amount , Coins type )
        {
            _internalWallet[ type ] += amount;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the given coin type and returns the in-game
        /// text color, which will be used when drawing the name
        /// within the game world.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <returns>The color associated with the coin enum to be used for rendering.</returns>
        public static Color ParseCoinTextColor( Coins type )
        {
            switch( type )
            {
                case Coins.Copper:
                    return CopperTextColor;
                case Coins.Silver:
                    return SilverTextColor;
                case Coins.Gold:
                    return GoldTextColor;
                case Coins.Platinum:
                    return PlatinumTextColor;
                default:
                    throw new Exception( "Could not parse Coin Color: " + type );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the current balance of a specified coin
        /// within the bag, then returns that value with the 
        /// appended abbreviation attached to the end of it.
        /// So, Coins.Copper would return "32c" if the current
        /// balance were 32 Copper at the time of invocation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="coin"></param>
        /// <returns>The abbreviated balance of the specified coin.</returns>
        public String CheckBalance( Coins coin )
        {
            switch( coin )
            {
                case Coins.Copper:
                    return "" + _internalWallet[ coin ] + CopperAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Silver:
                    return "" + _internalWallet[ coin ] + SilverAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Gold:
                    return "" + _internalWallet[ coin ] + GoldAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Platinum:
                    return "" + _internalWallet[ coin ] + PlatinumAbbreviation;
                default:
                    throw new Exception( "Could not parse Abbreviated Render text: " + coin );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the given coin type and returns the in-game
        /// string abbreviation. Coins.Copper returns 'c'; etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <returns>The char abbreviation associated with the coin enum.</returns>
        public static char ParseAbbreviation( Coins type )
        {
            switch( type )
            {
                case Coins.Copper:
                    return CopperAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Silver:
                    return SilverAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Gold:
                    return GoldAbbreviation;
                case Coins.Platinum:
                    return PlatinumAbbreviation;
                default:
                    throw new Exception( "Could not parse Coin Abbreviation: " + type );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the given coin type and returns the in-game
        /// string name. Coins.Copper returns "Copper"; etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <returns>The String name associated with the coin enum.</returns>
        public static String ParseName( Coins type )
        {
            switch( type )
            {
                case Coins.Copper:
                    return CopperName;
                case Coins.Silver:
                    return SilverName;
                case Coins.Gold:
                    return GoldName;
                case Coins.Platinum:
                    return PlatinumName;
                default:
                    throw new Exception( "Could not parse Coin Name: " + type );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases the current balance of this bag with the
        /// desired currency.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="platinum">The amount of platinum to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="gold">The amount of gold to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="silver">The amount of silver to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="copper">The amount of copper to be added.</param>
        public void Add( uint platinum , uint gold , uint silver , uint copper )
        {
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ] += copper;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ] += silver;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ] += gold;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ] += platinum;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases the current balance of this bag with the 
        /// current balance of another.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bag">The other bag.</param>
        public void Add( CoinBag bag )
        {
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ] += bag.Copper;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ] += bag.Silver;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ] += bag.Gold;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ] += bag.Platinum;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts the chosen currency by a desired amount.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">The amount to subtract.</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type of money that will be subtracted.</param>
        public void Subtract( uint amount , Coins type )
        {
            _internalWallet[ type ] -= amount;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts the current balance of the Coinbag with
        /// the desired fields.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="platinum">The amount of Platinum to subtract.</param>
        /// <param name="gold">The amount of Gold to subtract.</param>
        /// <param name="silver">The amount of silver to subtract.</param>
        /// <param name="copper">The amount of copper to subtract.</param>
        public void Subtract( uint platinum , uint gold , uint silver , uint copper )
        {
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ] -= copper;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ] -= silver;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ] -= gold;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ] -= platinum;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts the current balance of the Coinbag with
        /// the balance of another.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bag">The second bag.</param>
        public void Subtract( CoinBag bag )
        {
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ] -= bag.Copper;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ] -= bag.Silver;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ] -= bag.Gold;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ] -= bag.Platinum;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Completley Balances the current CoinBag by shifting
        /// over Copper->Silver->Gold->Platinum.
        /// </summary>
        public void Balance()
        {
            Exchange( Coins.Copper , Coins.Silver , Copper );
            Exchange( Coins.Silver , Coins.Gold , Silver );
            Exchange( Coins.Gold , Coins.Platinum , Gold );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Completely Empties the wallet of all money.
        /// </summary>
        public void Empty()
        {
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Copper ] -= 0;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Silver ] -= 0;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Gold ] -= 0;
            _internalWallet[ Coins.Platinum ] -= 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exchanges one field of currency to another based
        /// upon its monetary worth. The exchange rate for
        /// all currency is 100 of the lesser.
        /// 100 Gold = 1 Platinum.
        /// 100 Silver = 1 Gold.
        /// 100 Copper = 1 Silver.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fromType">The Type that will be exchanged.</param>
        /// <param name="toType">What the fromType will be exchanged to.</param>
        /// <param name="amountOfFromType">The amount to be exchanged.</param>
        public void Exchange( Coins fromType , Coins toType , long amountOfFromType )
        {
            if( fromType == toType )
                return;

            long fromTypeAmount = _internalWallet[ fromType ];
            if( amountOfFromType > fromTypeAmount )
                return; // Not enough money.
            if( fromType > toType )
            {
                _internalWallet[ toType ] += amountOfFromType * ( long )Math.Pow( 100 , ( int )fromType - ( int )toType );
            }
            else
            {
                long overflow = amountOfFromType % 100;
                amountOfFromType -= overflow;
                _internalWallet[ toType ] += amountOfFromType / ( long )Math.Pow( 100 , ( int )toType - ( int )fromType );
            }
            _internalWallet[ fromType ] -= amountOfFromType;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a String representation for the current
        /// monetary state of the coinbag. The format is
        /// as follows:
        /// [ Platinum->Gold->Silver->Copper ]
        /// Or:
        /// [ 100p,23g,17s,780c ]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A String reprsentation of the Coinbag.</returns>
        public String ToCurrencyString()
        {
            return
                "" + Platinum + PlatinumAbbreviation + "," +
                Gold + GoldAbbreviation + "," +
                Silver + SilverAbbreviation + "," +
                Copper + CopperAbbreviation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd consider storing values as copper and only converting to other denominations for displaying purposes.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The game that I am making will feature a somewhat unique currency system. In most games like World of Warcraft, it automagically creates 1 gold coin when you gain 100 silver. In my game, your silver collection can increase and is only exchanged when you visit a bank and CHOOSE to convert it over to the higher denomination. This is realistic, too, because in real life you don't automagically create a dollar in your hand when you have 100 pennies. I would much rather stick with the current system, which sorts and calculates everything when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. First, assign values to `CurrencyType` to know what has higher value and use it for conversion.

```
public enum CurrencyType
{
    Copper = 1,
    Silver = 2,
    Gold = 3,
    Platinum = 4
}
```

Then have the `CurrencyData` class look the following. I would use long if you are concerned about astronomical numbers.

```
private readonly Dictionary<CurrencyType, long> data;

public long Platinum { get { return data[CurrencyType.Platinum]; } }
... properties for other currencies

public CurrencyData(long platinum, long gold, long silver, long copper)
{
    data = new Dictionary<CurrencyType, long>
    {
        { CurrencyType.Platinum, platinum },
        { CurrencyType.Gold, gold },
        { CurrencyType.Silver, silver },
        { CurrencyType.Copper, copper }
    };
}
```

and finally, a method for conversion

```
public void Exchange(CurrencyType fromType, CurrencyType toType, long amountOfFromType)
{
    if (fromType == toType)
        return;

    var fromTypeAmount = data[fromType];
    if (amountOfFromType > fromTypeAmount)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough money");

    if (fromType > toType)
    {
        data[toType] += amountOfFromType * (long) Math.Pow(100, (int)fromType - (int)toType);               
    }
    else
    {
        var overflow = amountOfFromType % 100;
        amountOfFromType -= overflow;
        data[toType] += amountOfFromType / (long) Math.Pow(100, (int)toType - (int)fromType);                               
    }

    data[fromType] -= amountOfFromType;         
}
```

You can try it with

```
wallet.Exchange(CurrencyType.Platinum, CurrencyType.Gold, 3);
wallet.Exchange(CurrencyType.Copper, CurrencyType.Silver, 125);
```

Comment: I chose you as the answer because you went above and beyond the call. You offered not only working code, but a great verbal explanation; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite simple. Use your CurrencyData object to hold the results. The rest is all mathematical. And since you are using 100 based units, then it's even simpler since you are using normal based numbering...

**Converting Down**
Simply move from top to bottom, and multiply by 100... not sure why you would ever do that but it's as simple as that!

***Examples***

```
 //gold to silver
 this.SilverCount += this.GoldCount * 100;
 this.GoldCount = 0;

 //silver to copper
 this.CopperCount += this.SilverCount * 100;
 this.SilverCount = 0;
```

**Converting Up**
Simply move from bottom to top, divide by 100, and keep the remainder...

***Examples***

```
 //copper to silver
 this.SilverCount += (this.CopperCount / 100);
 this.CopperCount = this.CopperCount % 100;

 //silver to gold
 this.GoldCount += (this.SilverCount / 100);
 this.SilverCount = this.SilverCount % 100;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Excellent. Looks really good. Oh, and I probably should have mentioned that I was wanting it to be fed in through mild variations, so instead of converting all your gold to silver at once, you can choose to just convert 23 out of your 40 gold coins to silver (allows for a dynamic banking system later)

Comment: It shames me greatly, too, that I forgot all about the modulus operator... >_>

Comment: @Krythic Great! Then you can code separate methods for each conversion, within the object itself. Note that i modified the code above a little to be more streamlined. I had also forgotten to keep the amount in the counts on Converting Down... the new code above should work properly.